# Fullcalendar - display events from several google calendars in vertical display in day view

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-scheduler

I put the fullCalendar plug-in on my site. It needs to display events from several google calendars. I did it by analogy from the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar)
(Multiple Google Calendars)

But events are displayed only on the week and month intervals, on the day interval, events are not displayed. They are displayed only if I remove the block (array) resources. But without it, the display of events inside the day becomes horizontal, but it needs to be vertical (shaded time zones of the event). When i manually fill events in events, everything works fine, but I need to take them from Google.

How do I get the events from google on the daily interval displayed in a vertical view?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
  scrollTime: '09:00:00',
  minTime: '08:00:00',
  googleCalendarApiKey: '<MY API KEY>',
  defaultView: 'agendaDay',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
  },
  eventSources: [
    {
      id: 'k01',
      resourceId: 'k01',
      googleCalendarId: 'hhug0bdep49rjgq4kk79rrjbgg@group.calendar.google.com', // 1 calendar
      color: 'blue',
    },
    {
      id: 'k02',
      resourceId: 'k02',
      googleCalendarId: 'db1ls6vg0fh9sgqt57fkethens@group.calendar.google.com' //2 calendar
    },
    {
      id: 'k03',
      resourceId: 'k03',
      googleCalendarId: 'ncvl95m9f8irl6nd3ejm99fvho@group.calendar.google.com' //3 calendar
    }
  ],
  resources: [
    { id: 'k01', title: 'calendar 1', eventColor: 'red'}, 
    { id: 'k02', title: 'calendar 2',},
    { id: 'k03', title: 'calendar 3'}
  ]
});
```

[image: Vertical view in day view]

Comment: I should think this is because your events coming from Google will not have resource IDs. If there is no resource ID, it is impossible for fullCalendar to know which column to display it in, so it cannot display it at all. Also, the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view says "If you would like resource column functionality in a multi-day view...which is **turned off by default**, you’ll need to activate either the `groupByResource` or `groupByDateAndResource` flags." (my bold). So make sure you do not set either of these options to `true`.

Comment: ADyson, I set these values to false, but it did not change anything, the daily interval is displayed horizontally. "I should think this is because your events coming from Google will not have resource IDs. If there is no resource ID, it is impossible for fullCalendar to know which column to display it in, so it cannot display it at all." Yes, it is possible, but is there a possibility to set up a resource IDs? I set it in EventSurces, but for some reason it does not pick up. Maybe there is some other way?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object does not say that putting resourceId as a parameter of an event source object is valid. Did you check that before trying? That is the reason it isn't picked up, because it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your events coming from Google will not have resource IDs. If there is no resource ID, it is impossible for fullCalendar to know which column to display it in, so it cannot display it at all.

To stop the agendaDay view from displaying with resources, you need to set the option groupByDateAndResource to false:

```
groupByDateAndResource: false
```

Although the documentation says this is false by default, it appears you do have to explicitly set this option in your calendar config for it to work.

See http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/63/ for a working example (you can fill in your API key to see actual event data, but it shows the layout correctly).